# Making a Settings.txt File - How to load settings the right way?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

I have an app I'm working on and it should save and load settings through an XML file (named `Settings.txt`)
Now, here's the code I use:

```
public class Settings
{
    public bool Selected_64Bit { get; set; }
    public bool Supported_64Bit { get; set; }
    public bool FirstTime { get; set; }
}

static void SaveSettings(Settings settings)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("settings.txt"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, settings);
    }
}

static Settings LoadSettings()
{
    if (!File.Exists("settings.txt"))
        return new Settings();

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead("settings.txt"))
    {
        return (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to load the settings into a new `Settings()`.
I found out that doing:

```
Settings [VAR] = new Settings()
```

will make a new `Settings()` with all `false`, but I want to LOAD the saved settings..
I'm confused and can't explain this to myself...

The final product should:

- Check if `settings.txt` exists
- If it does - LOAD SETTINGS into a new `Settings` called `Setting` (in my case).
- If it doesn't - Make new settings and then save them.

I hope someone understood and can help me.
BTW - I'm not so good in C#, and I don't get the get\set thingy at all, as of return and other methods like that.. I know the basics and I'll be happy if I won't need more complicated techniques.
And if I must use more complicated techniques - please explain them deeply because I DO NOT KNOW.

Comment: The .NET framework already provides a really very nice system of both app and user settings. Any reason why you aren't using that?

Comment: The .net settings wont work as good as I need it to work - it's more complicated in any way than settings thing I mentioned

Comment: It's really not that complicated. It's `Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting` to get and set `MySetting` and you just save it with `Save`. It handles default values when the settings file isn't present and it has a nice interface in Visual Studio for adding new properties. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As you have it set up, you'd need to do:

```
Settings mySettings = Settings.LoadSettings();
```

This will run your static `LoadSettings` method and return a `Settings` object.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt already wrote

```
Settings mySettings = Settings.LoadSettings();
```

will do the job.

If you have a application you could use its settings as well. You get that settings by Properties.Settings.Default and in your project settings you can define some properties.